# how do I run a python script that requires pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I got a python file which using something called pyparsing but when I run it It showed an error that pyparsing is required can any one pls tel me what to do 
not that I am a dump in that thing called pything I need to run that script only :)thanks

Comment: Please paste (part of) your source and the exact error message you are receiving so we can provide an answer specific to your problem instead of guessing that pyparsing isn't available on your $PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If pyparsing is required, and you haven't got it, you need to install it.  See https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/ and/or https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing for instructions.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Comment: @PaulMcG Thanks for the heads up. For future reference, if you see broken links in any answer of mine, just go ahead and edit the answer to correct it.